# Calling transferFrom of external erc20 contract

Tags: solidity, erc-20, security

Hey I'm calling externals contract method transferFrom in following way.

```
function sendTransaction(address tokenAddress, uint tokenAmount) public payable {
    if (!performTransfer(tokenAddress, tokenAmount)) {
        revert();
    }

function performTransfer(address tokenAddress, uint amount) internal returns (bool) {
    ERC20Interface instance = ERC20Interface(tokenAddress); 
    bool resp = instance.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amount); 
    return resp;
}
```

Can someone please tell me if there are any security vulnerabilities in those two functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing I see is your method `sendTransaction` don't need to have modifier `payable`, because it's not dealing with ethers, but with ERC20 token. And you might wanna return true when `sendTransaction` succeed.

```
function sendTransaction(address tokenAddress, uint tokenAmount) public returns (bool) {
    require(performTransfer(tokenAddress, tokenAmount));
    return true;
}

function performTransfer(address tokenAddress, uint amount) internal returns (bool) {
    ERC20Interface instance = ERC20Interface(tokenAddress); 
    return instance.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amount);
}
```

Comment: Ah thanks for your tips! Really appreciate! :)